# Force change owner of windows 7 user folder

Tags: windows-7, permissions, ownership

I copied my c:\users folder to my external drive and now I want to access it in another PC but it says I don't have permissions to access and I can't change the owner of it.

How can I force to change the owner of the folder? source dir was NTFS and account had password (that I know)

Comment: You might describe what error you are getting and at what stage when attempting to change ownership....http://www.blogsdna.com/2159/how-to-take-ownership-grant-permissions-to-access-files-folder-in-windows-7.htm

Comment: You need to take ownership of the folders. Then you need to give yourself permission to the folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version you may need to be in safe mode to do this.

Right click on the folder and go to the security tab. Click advanced, and go to the ownership tad. This'll allow you to change the owner of the file.

Comment: Yeah, you have to seize ownership of the folder though the Security tab. Then give all users read access to the folder.

Comment: Followed this tutorial: http://www.blogsdna.com/2159/how-to-take-ownership-grant-permissions-to-access-files-folder-in-windows-7.htm and it works