# Grant access to User folder on external drive

Tags: windows-7, permissions, user-folders

I have recently replaced my notebook's HDD with an SSD, and reinstalled Windows 7 on the SSD. I bought a caddy for the "old" HDD, and I can successfully boot windows from the SSD.

I can see the **old** HDD as an external drive; however, I can't access my user folder on it. When I try to open the user folder, I get this error:

[image]

If I click on `Continue`, nothing really happens. The green bar shows and loads (like "I'm getting your files!"), but once it reaches the end, I cannot enter the folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: [`takeown`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024.aspx)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/268445/force-change-owner-of-windows-7-user-folder

Comment: @techie007 please add your response as an answer so that BeNdErR can mark it and close this question. Else please flag it as duplicate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't delete folder, need permission from adminstrator?](http://superuser.com/questions/289766/cant-delete-folder-need-permission-from-adminstrator)

Comment: @GaneshR. I'd have marked it as a dupe, but I'm out of close-votes for the day.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to delete folder in windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/321468/unable-to-delete-folder-in-windows-7)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lack of permission to open user folder](http://superuser.com/questions/210993/lack-of-permission-to-open-user-folder)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the command [`takeown`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024.aspx) to take ownership of user folders and thus regain access to your files (or anyone elses's) on the old hard-disk.

(from [techie007](https://superuser.com/users/23133/techie007)'s comment above.

```
C:\>takeown /?

TAKEOWN [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]]
        /F filename [/A] [/R [/D prompt]]

Description:
    This tool allows an administrator to recover access to a file that
    was denied by re-assigning file ownership.

Parameter List:
    /S           system          Specifies the remote system to
                                 connect to.

    /U           [domain\]user   Specifies the user context under
                                 which the command should execute.

    /P           [password]      Specifies the password for the
                                 given user context.
                                 Prompts for input if omitted.

    /F           filename        Specifies the filename or directory
                                 name pattern. Wildcard "*" can be used
                                 to specify the pattern. Allows
                                 sharename\filename.

    /A                           Gives ownership to the administrators
                                 group instead of the current user.

    /R                           Recurse: instructs tool to operate on
                                 files in specified directory and all
                                 subdirectories.

    /D           prompt          Default answer used when the current user
                                 does not have the "list folder" permission
                                 on a directory.  This occurs while operating
                                 recursively (/R) on sub-directories. Valid
                                 values "Y" to take ownership or "N" to skip.

    /?                           Displays this help message.

    NOTE: 1) If /A is not specified, file ownership will be given to the
             current logged on user.

          2) Mixed patterns using "?" and "*" are not supported.

          3) /D is used to suppress the confirmation prompt.

Examples:
    TAKEOWN /?
    TAKEOWN /F lostfile
    TAKEOWN /F \\system\share\lostfile /A
    TAKEOWN /F directory /R /D N
    TAKEOWN /F directory /R /A
    TAKEOWN /F *
    TAKEOWN /F C:\Windows\System32\acme.exe
    TAKEOWN /F %windir%\*.txt
    TAKEOWN /S system /F MyShare\Acme*.doc
    TAKEOWN /S system /U user /F MyShare\foo.dll
    TAKEOWN /S system /U domain\user /P password /F share\filename
    TAKEOWN /S system /U user /P password /F Doc\Report.doc /A
    TAKEOWN /S system /U user /P password /F Myshare\*
    TAKEOWN /S system /U user /P password /F Home\Logon /R
    TAKEOWN /S system /U user /P password /F Myshare\directory /R /A
```

Example from Vista. It should be similar on Windows 7.

Comment: Awesome, and I can confirm this works on windows 10 too

Comment: +1 because `TAKEOWN /F E:\Users\*` worked for me though i suppose i sholdve done: `TAKEOWN /F E:\Users\user\*`

Comment: I had to run the `cmd` as administrator and also recursive: `TAKEOWN /F E:\Users\* /R`

Answer (score 0):

- Just change your new account to administrator role.
- Plug in the HDD, navigate to desired folder's parent location.
- Right mouse click on desired folder.
- Click on properties.
- Select security tab.
- Click on Advanced.
- Click on Change in front of Owner.
- Add your current user as owner
- Once all the files and folder are under your ownership, close and reopen the folder to access.

Comment: How is this better than other answer? More than 8 years after.